# Axios interceptor refreshes tokens for one of my requests but the rest of them returns 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have created a axios interceptor in react for handling the authenticated request to my django backend.

My code:

useAxios.js

```js
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import axios from 'axios'
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext';

const useAxios = () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3001'

    const { authTokens, setUser, setAuthTokens } = useContext(AuthContext)
    
    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: url,
    });

    // Response interceptor to handle 401 and 403 errors and refresh the token
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
        (response) => {
            return response;
        },
        async (error) => {
            if (error.response) {
                if (error.response.status === 401 && !error.config._retry) {
                    error.config._retry = true;

                    const response = await axios.post(`${url}/api/token/refresh`, {
                        refresh: authTokens.refresh
                    });

                    const tokens = response.data

                    console.log('response interceptor',tokens)

                    localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(tokens))

                    setAuthTokens(tokens)
                    setUser(jwtDecode(tokens.access))

                    error.config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokens.access}`;

                    return axiosInstance(error.config);
                }
            }

            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );

    return axiosInstance
};

export default useAxios;
```

Also i have created a Auth context provider for handling login and other function.

AuthContext.js

```js
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export default AuthContext;

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

    // For getting user detail from the access token
    let [user, setUser] = useState(() => localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null);
    // For setting the auth tokes from the backend
    let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(() => localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null);
    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    let loginUser = async (formValues) => {
        let response = await fetch('/api/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'username': formValues.username,
                'password': formValues.password
            })
        });

        // returns {"access": "key", "refresh": "key"}
        let data = await response.json()
        
        if (response.status === 200) {
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwtDecode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
            navigate("/")
        }

        if (response.status === 401) {
            return data
        }

        if (response.status === 400) {
            return data
        }
    }

    let registerUser = async (formValues) => {
        const epochTime = Math.floor(new Date(formValues.expire).getTime() / 1000)

        let response = await fetch('/api/users', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'firstname': formValues.firstname,
                'lastname': formValues.lastname,
                'username': formValues.username,
                'email': formValues.email,
                'password': formValues.password,
                'expire': epochTime
            })
        });

        let data = await response.json()

        if (response.status === 201) {
            return data
        }

        if (response.status === 400) {
            return data
        }
    }

    let logoutUser = () => {
        setAuthTokens(null)
        setUser(null)
        localStorage.removeItem('authTokens')
        navigate("/login")
    }

    let contextData = {
        user: user,
        setUser: setUser,
        authTokens: authTokens,
        setAuthTokens: setAuthTokens,
        loginUser: loginUser,
        registerUser: registerUser,
        logoutUser: logoutUser
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (authTokens) {
            setUser(jwtDecode(authTokens.access))
        }
        setLoading(false)
    }, [authTokens, loading]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
            {loading ? null : children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

And this is part of my HomePage.js

```js
let api = useAxios()

    useEffect(() => {
        const getVms = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await api.get(`/api/vms/vm/${user.username}`)

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log(response)
                }

                const res = await api.get(`/api/vms/vm/104/status`)

                if (res.status === 200) {
                    console.log(res)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }

        getVms();
    }, []);
```

The problem is that my response interceptor when recieves the 401 refreshes the tokens and retrys the first request that in the end returns 200

[image]

but the second request returns 401 so the interceptor kicks in but also returns 401 because its trying to refresh with the old key.

[image]
[image]

Also should mention that in my backend you can refresh tokens with a refresh key that after one refresh then it expires.

My console:

[image]

Can someone explain why something like this is happening and how can i address such an issue??